# Dates in custom queries doesn't show correctly in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom query in wordpress to show the past events in a page named **page-past-event.php** .This is my code:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div class="page-banner">
    <div class="page-banner__bg-image"
         style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri( '/images/ocean.jpg' );
 ?>

                 );"></div>

    <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title">Past Events</h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
            <p>A recap of our past events.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container container--narrow page-section">

    <?php

    $today = date( 'Ymd' );

$pastEvents = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type'  => 'event',
        'meta_key'   => 'event_date',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_date',
                'compare' => '<',
                'value'   => $today,
                'type'    => 'numeric'
            )
        )

    ) );
while ( $pastEvents->have_posts() ) {
$pastEvents->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="event-summary">
            <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <span class="event-summary__month">
                            <?php
 try {
                                $eventDate = new DateTime( get_field( 'event_date' ) );
                            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                            }
                            echo $eventDate->format( 'M' );
                            ?></span>
                <span class="event-summary__day"><?php echo $eventDate->format( 'd' ); ?></span>
            </a>
<div class="event-summary__content">
                <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 18 ); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
the_post_thumbnail();

        the_author_posts_link();
        ?>
        on
        <?php
        the_time( 'n.j.y' );
        ?>
        in category
        <?php
        echo get_the_category_list( ', ' );
    ?>


        <?php
    }

    echo paginate_links();
    ?>




    <?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

And I am using  **Advanced custom fields** and **Akismet Anti-Spam** plugins ,by the way.
The problem is the wordpress navigation menu that is on top of the homepage of the theme and  page-past-event.php , is gone (but when I am in other pages like admin dashboard the wordpress default menu exists) also the content of the site in homepage and the page-past-event.php page is gone.I also took screenshot from the crucial parts of admin dashboard that may caused this problem :

[image]

and the permalinks settings:
[image]
Thank you for your attention.

**UPDATE 1** : I noticed this error on my front-page.php after makes wp_debug , on , this is the error :

Notice: Undefined variable: Upcoming Events

NOTICE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: EVENTDATE IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\IPCONCRETE\WP-CONTENT\THEMES\FICTIONAL-UNIVERSITY\FRONT-PAGE.PHP ON LINE 185

FATAL ERROR: UNCAUGHT ERROR: CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION FORMAT() ON NULL IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\IPCONCRETE\WP-CONTENT\THEMES\FICTIONAL-UNIVERSITY\FRONT-PAGE.PHP:185 STACK TRACE: #0 C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\IPCONCRETE\WP-INCLUDES\TEMPLATE-LOADER.PHP(98): INCLUDE() #1 C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\IPCONCRETE\WP-BLOG-HEADER.PHP(19): REQUIRE_ONCE('C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS...') #2 C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\IPCONCRETE\INDEX.PHP(17): REQUIRE('C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS...') #3 {MAIN} THROWN IN C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS\IPCONCRETE\WP-CONTENT\THEMES\FICTIONAL-UNIVERSITY\FRONT-PAGE.PHP ON LINE 185

And the code associated with line 185 of front-page.php is :

```
$eventDate = new DateTime( get_field( 'event_date' ) );
echo $eventDate->format( 'M' );
```

Comment: The page is blank probably because you have a php error. Do you have WP_DEBUG enabled?

Comment: @HowardE Thank you I will update the question, but I never change the codes in the files that errors are referring to

Comment: Have you tried re-setting your permalinks back to plain?

Comment: @HowardE Yes I did.

Comment: @HowardE Nothing happened.